# how can I set cookie after the completion of form and use these cookie on another page

Tags: jquery, surveyjs

my issue is when user completed the survey and click on complete button then i want to redirect user to another page and showing some result related to result Json data on that page (redirected page).

so i want to create cookie when user click on complete button and use those cookie on redirected page. but i could not do so.

```
Survey.StylesManager.applyTheme("modern");

var resultId = '';

var surveySendResult = function(s, options) {
  if (options.success) {
    s.getResult(resultId, 'hair_type');
  }
};

var surveyGetResult = function(s, options) {
  if (options.success) {
    //         showChart(options.dataList);
  }
};

function showChart(chartDataSource) {
  document.getElementById("chartContainer").style.height = "500px";
  $("#chartContainer").dxPieChart({
    dataSource: chartDataSource,
    series: {
      argumentField: 'name',
      valueField: 'value'
    }
  });
}

var json = {
  surveyId: '',
  surveyPostId: '',
  "cookieName": "915324d6-f652-437c-a09b-62464259f55d",
};

window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);

survey.onComplete.add(function(sender) {
  document.querySelector('#surveyResult').textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3);
  setCookie(sender);
});

function setCookie(survey) {
  var data = survey.data;
  survey.setCookie(JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log("cookie is created");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(survey.data, null, 3));
  getCookie(survey);
}

function getCookie(sender) {
  if (survey.hasCookie) {
    console.log("sdgfv");
    document.querySelector('#surveyResult').textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3));
  }
}

$("#surveyElement").Survey({
  model: survey,
  onSendResult: surveySendResult,
  onGetResult: surveyGetResult
});
```

Comment: Why couldn't you set the cookie? It looks like you're doing it with `survey.setCookie()`. But `getCookie()` never reads the cookie, it just checks if it's set.

Comment: can you tell me what should i do? for get cookie

Comment: I'm not familiar with survey.js, but if there's `survey.setCookie()` I assume there's a `survey.getCookie()` to retrieve it. I guess that code goes in the next page that you're redirecting to.